# Get the view which was dismissed and from which the current view is display

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have a `NavigationView` which is showing a different view via `fullScreenCover` when I press a Button. Now I need to know when my view from where I pressed the Button is getting visible again and what was the view before. In the view shown by the `fullScreenCover` im using `@Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss` to dismiss it.

So here is my concrete use case:

- I have my main screen with two Buttons A and B.
- A is showing sub view 1 and B is showing sub view 2.
- When I dismiss one of these sub screens I need to know if I was in A view 1 or 2 before.

Is this somehow possible?

Comment: Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot. It depends on your setup but the simplest is probably by using a `didSet` or `onChange` on the variable that shows 1 and 2 it should change to `false` when you dismiss.

Comment: hi @gureghbgui, have the answers you've got fully answered your question? If not may you edit your question to include any missing information / an example of what you tried to do ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.onDisappear` on the view that is linked on the `destination` of the `NavigationLink`. See this example:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var selectedSubView: ViewSelection = ViewSelection.zero

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                // Version 1
                NavigationLink (
                    destination: SubView1()
                        .onDisappear {
                            self.selectedSubView = .one
                            print(self.selectedSubView) // debug
                        },
                    label: {
                        Text("To ViewOne").padding()
                    })
                // Version 2
                NavigationLink (
                    destination: SubView2()
                        .onDisappear {
                        self.selectedSubView = .two
                        print(self.selectedSubView) // debug
                    },
                    label: {
                        Text("To ViewTwo")
                            .padding()
                    })
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SubView1: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("View 1")
    }
}

struct SubView2: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("View 2")
    }
}

enum ViewSelection {
    case one
    case two
    case zero
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.fullScreenCover` with an `onDismiss` closure.
(Here I used `.sheet` because it's easier to test, but it's the same)

```
struct SwiftUIView4: View {
    @State private var destination: Destination?
    @State private var showed: Destination?
    @State private var dismissed: Destination?

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Button("A") {
                    destination = .firstView
                    showed = .firstView
                }.padding()
                Spacer()
                Button("B") {
                    destination = .secondView
                    showed = .secondView
                }.padding()
            }
            Text("Just dismissed : \(dismissed?.rawValue ?? "nothing")")
                .sheet(item: $destination, onDismiss: {
                    dismissed = showed
                }, content: { destination in
                    switch destination {
                    case .firstView: Text("A clicked")
                    case .secondView: Text("B clicked")
                    }
                })
        }
    }
}

enum Destination: String, Identifiable {
    case firstView, secondView
    var id: Destination { self }
}
```

Or you could use a custom `Binding` for the `item` parameter of your `.fullScreenCover` :

```
struct SwiftUIView4: View {
    @State private var showed: Destination?
    @State private var dismissed: Destination?

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Button("A") {
                    showed = .firstView
                }.padding()
                Spacer()
                Button("B") {
                    showed = .secondView
                }.padding()
            }
            Text("Just dismissed : \(dismissed?.rawValue ?? "nothing")")
                .sheet(item: .init(get: {showed}, set: {
                    dismissed = showed  // HERE
                    showed = $0         // <<<<
                })) { destination in
                    switch destination {
                    case .firstView: Text("A clicked")
                    case .secondView: Text("B clicked")
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```